# Running a bootstrap shell script to install apache on an ec2: "No such file or directory"

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

Doing a lab for AWS class. We launch an Ec2 and in the configure setting type a script that *should* automatically start and run Apache web server. However entering the script/text via the management console, it obviously does not install the webserver:
[screenshot of instructions from the textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xci3T.png)

[screenshot of the  script we're expected to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myB7h.png)

I've already mananged to install a different apache webserver on the ec2 using a different method; terminal on mac using:

```
yum install -y httpd.x86_64
```

and now i initiate it on startup with:

```
systemctl start httpd.service
```

so now, obviously it works the workaround way i have installed but, i want to know why the site/public ip4 can't be reach when trying **just** the books method:

```
#include https://s3.amazonaws.com/jbawsbook/bootstrap.sh
```

again i did it the way the book instructed, which was during the initiial set up of the ec2. but i've also tried to run it via bash after ssh into the ec2. the results are the same no matter how i've tried it. obviously i may be doing something wrong since im just learning? and yes i've tried running the script via amazon linux 2 as well.

```
bash: https://s3.amazonaws.com/jbawsbook/bootstrap.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you use:

```sh
#include
https://s3.amazonaws.com/jbawsbook/bootstrap.sh
```

From [CloudInit - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit):

> **Include File** begins with `#include` or `Content-Type: text/x-include-url`
>
> This content is a "include" file. The file contains **a list of urls, one per line**. Each of the URLs will be read, and their content will be passed through this same set of rules. Ie, the content read from the URL can be gzipped, mime-multi-part, or plain text

So, it looks like the publisher lost the newline.

Comment: Oh wow. That's nice. Thank you. Is this new feature or was always there?

Comment: Even with editing the userdata with that script **and line break**, the ip is timing out. "ip-xx-xxx took too long to respond". 

i've checked my security group and my inboard settings allows all traffic at http-port 80.

Comment: You can view the cloud-init output log file at: `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

Comment: im getting:
 `[root@ip-172-xx-xx-xxx ec2-user]# /var/log/cloud-init-output.log
bash: /var/log/cloud-init-output.log: Permission denied`

i may have to delete this instance and start over. i've given it iam roles just now thinking maybe that was this issue, it couldnt access s3. but that still hasn't helped.

Comment: You can view it with `cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log`, or you might need `sudo cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log`